# List of symbols wherein position encoded by number to string

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

How to transform list wherein position of the symbol encoded by number at second position

```
{{a,6},{z,1},{g,2},{y,12}}
```

to string

```
zg---a-----y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = {{a, 6}, {z, 1}, {g, 2}, {y, 12}};

#2 -> ToString[#] & @@@ list // Append[_ -> "-"] // SparseArray // StringJoin
```

> `"zg---a-----y"`

Comment: `SparseArray` is very clever. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

One more alternative, using `StringReplacePart[]`:

```
l = {{"a", 6}, {"z", 1}, {"g", 2}, {"y", 12}};
str = StringJoin[ConstantArray["-", Max[l[[All, -1]]]]];
Fold[StringReplacePart[#1, Sequence @@ #2] &, str,
     MapAt[ConstantArray[#, 2] &, l, {All, -1}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Pre-processing:

```
str = {{a, 6}, {z, 1}, {g, 2}, {y, 12}};
len = Max@Last@Transpose@str
out = StringRepeat["-", len]
```

String manipulations:

```
repl = {ToString /@ #1, Transpose@{#2, #2}} & @@ (Transpose@str)
StringReplacePart[out, #1, #2] & @@ repl
```

> "zg---a-----y"

Answer (score 2):

Modify a string of "-"s with the correct length:

```
list = {{a,6},{z,1},{g,2},{y,12}};
len = Max[list[[All, 2]]];
chars = ConstantArray["-", len];
Do[chars[[s[[2]]]] = ToString @ s[[1]], {s, list}];
StringJoin[chars]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the first answer, this keeps list as a list until the end:

```
list = {{a, 6}, {z, 1}, {g, 2}, {y, 12}}; 
Fold[ ReplacePart[ #1, #2[[2]] -> ToString @ #2[[1]] ] &
    , Table["-", 12], list] // StringJoin
```